# Elasticsearch cluster with all master and data on same nodes. Is it a good idea?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I have some doubts on ES. We have configured three node ES cluster with all acting both as master and data at the same time. On the top of it we are having ELB so logstash will send traffic to ELB first. Is it a good idea or do we need to make dedicated master server to manage its tasks.

Comment: what are your concerns? what exactly is that you want to know?

Answer (score 0):

You're asking two different questions.

First, they suggest running dedicated master nodes (non-data nodes).  We've experienced master nodes having performance problems and interfering with indexing (maybe single-threaded somewhere?), so it seems to make sense.

Second, by sending your data to one of your three data nodes, there's a 66% chance that the data won't be there.  If you were to use a client node, it would be able to route the request to the correct nodes.

Hope that helps.